# RSA algorithm encrypted result changing when receiving through POST in YII

Tags: php, algorithm, encryption, yii, rsa

We are using RSA algorithm for encryption using yii.

We have an array and we encrypted this array using RSA algoritham in yii.

When the encrypted array passed through `$_POST` the string changed and getting some other string like as follows:-

Input:

> - b¯ uÁGÒJÒ•ŠR™Tè6–Â›v   Ü8É]uÃc,oæ?ëÂí´7f©¹I¡KËzämwf!L}d¸dÜ’²3¬T%ë„íˆÙ8-Fs@pÚ™Ö™¡dÔ®u›HN^n*G=Ž
>     r•éŒHƒ'ƒèSRAEgŸ±KXi4›U3°b~¶¸zj\áñs ù½‹Ó îÀÝñ¬ “àÅ‚×Ò¨^×²5¸zœŒÛõl
>     ¨Z›3’Ä—ì²VQïŸH›;oz”£ ÿ
>     F›VNú»r   ?+¬+XÖ1üÍï6ôy®Sc€8èîåßbVª¹ßàsZFS=7!MºŒ…ÏPhyãæ}Vªó 384b¯

```
   |
 $_POST
   |
```

Output:

> - uÁGÒJÒ•ŠR™Tè6–Â›v   Ü8É]uÃc,oæ?ëÂí´7f©¹I¡KËzämwf!L}d¸dÜ’²3¬T%ë„íˆÙ8-Fs@pÚ™Ö™¡dÔ®u›HN^n*G=Ž
>     r•éŒHƒ'ƒèSRAEgŸ±KXi4›U3°b~¶¸zj\áñs ù½‹Ó îÀÝñ¬ “àÅ‚×Ò¨^×²5¸zœŒÛõl
>     ¨Z›3’Ä—ì²VQïŸH›;oz”£ ÿ F›VNú»r    ? ¬
>     XÖ1üÍï6ôy®Sc€8èîåßbVª¹ßàsZFS=7!MºŒ…ÏPhyãæ}Vªó

See the output encrypted format is not as in input.

Is any limitation for encrypted format for passing through `$_POST` ??

Comment: Yes, you need to encode it, because HTTP doesn't support binary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can RSA Encrypted Data be Sent Over HTTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316838/can-rsa-encrypted-data-be-sent-over-http)